# I am having difficulty putting a menu in my tkinter app

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, menu

I guess the way that I am doing while writing this code is I am bringing up all the windows then showing them when needed I am just starting tkinter and going off a tutorial to shape it the way I want. I have multiple windows but only showing code for the first one I want the menu to be on that is why I have a try and except clause in the show frame. I found a similar code on another stackoverflow question having the same problem I am having but the fix is not working and I don't know what to do. Please help.
Here is my code:

```
class TradingBotapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side='top',fill='both',expand= True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight = 1)
        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage,Login,Register,Main_Page,InitalSetup):
            frame = F(container,self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nsew')

        self.show_frame(Main_Page)

    def show_frame(self,cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        try:
            self["menu"] = frame.menu
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        frame.tkraise()

class Main_Page(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.init_window(controller)
        label = tk.Label(self, text='Main Page', font = LARGE_FONT).pack()


    def init_window(self,controller):
        StockWatchList = ['Dave','Pam','Girl','Guy','Boy']

        self.grid(column=0,row=0)
        menu = tk.Menu(self)
        file = tk.Menu(menu)
        file.add_command(label='Exit')

        StockWatch = tk.Menu(menu)
        for stock in StockWatchList:
            StockWatch.add_command(label=stock)

        self.menu
app = TradingBotapp()
app.mainloop()
```

The fix that was on the stackoverflow question was to put `self["menu"] = frame.menu` in the show frame and to put `self.menu` where you want to show it rather than putting I think `self.master.config(menu=menu)` Any help would be much appreciated thanks!

Comment: If you're just starting to learn tkinter, I personally recommend finding a different tutorial. You need to start with something that doesn't use multiple frames -- that design was never intended to be something for beginners, and it adds a lot of complexity when you're just starting out.

Comment: I am almost done with my app using this way. I don't want to start over. This is not my first window, I just showed the one to truncate it.

Comment: So I found watched the rest of his tutorial and found out how to do it, he put the menu items under the main app